# Python-docx: Structure problem. One Paragraph contains two objects

Tags: python, python-docx

the situation is I want to print the text from the paragraph.
When I code

```
doc.paragraphs[i].text
```

It comes two lines. Like:

```
ABC
DEFG
```

Than I think it contains two lists, So code as blow to get the first list only:

```
doc.paragraphs[i].text[0]
```

However, the result is not like what I think, it becomes:

```
A
D
```

I have no idea why it could be that?
How can I do to get the first list "ABC" ??

btw. [i] is one of paragraphs from document

===Update===

I have got my problem.
The reason why it got two objects is because my if condition:

```
for i in range(0,100):
  if 'abc' in doc.paragraphs[i].text:
    print(doc.paragraphs[i].text)
```

However, 'abc' appeared two times in the two lines.
So, it comes two objects.
Now I fix the code like:

```
if 'abc' == doc.paragraphs[i].text:
```

Then, it comes one object! Sorry for my stupid Orz

Comment: It appears that the text has an explicit line break. So it is not a 2-list but a string. You can't use subscripting to do what you want, as you have discovered. Split the text on line break, which is the character at `doc.paragraphs[i].text[3]` in your example. Look in the documentation for the `.split()` string method.

Comment: Hi, I had tried to use   `doc.paragraphs[i].text[0].split()`, but still got two character `['A'] ['D']`, and if I code `doc.paragraphs[i].text[3].split()`, the result comes `['G'] IndexError: string index out of range`

Comment: I say again: `doc.paragraphs[i].text` is *not a 2-list but a string*. So `.text[0]` gives you the first *character*. If you want to split the string on whitespace, you call `doc.paragraphs[i].text.split()`. That produces a list which you can then subscript.

Comment: I know what you mean, but if I  code `type(doc.paragraphs[i].text)`, it comes `<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>`. There are also two string object but not a string. So the solution you give, may not help.

Comment: Do this: `type(doc.paragraphs[i].text.split())`. What do you get?

Comment: Show us the rest of the code. Where does the `i` come from and what loop does this execute in?

Comment: @scanny I found my problem and solved it ! Sorry for my stupid :(

Comment: @BoarGules Thank you for answering my question, I found my mistake in the code, and update the content.